# libogg/libvorbis projects for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ogg, vorbis

I recently installed VS2010 and am in the process of recompiling some libraries. It went ok until it was time for libobb and libvorbis. The conversion of the projectfiles failed for some reason. 
Has somebody had some experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drac667 on freenode #vorbis maintains the Windows build files. There was some big conversion going on around 20th September.

Try checking out the source again; it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got some help cleaning up the project files already, but it is good to know that it won't be an issue in the future.